# CSS file got flooded with errors after VSC update

Tags: html, css, grid, ssas

Yesterday I was working on my code as usual and everything was going fine.
Today, however, after turning on VSC I spotted that my CSS file got flooded with errors, I have no idea what happened.

Here's one example of code that worked before and now it's broken:

```
.portfolio {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[6];
      grid-template-columns repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 300px 400px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
```

I made a screenshot so you guys can see what I mean since it's my first post here and I hope it all seems clear.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/txK0n.png

Also, there is an even weirder occurrence that I can't handle, any ideas?

```
.nav {
  display: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 66%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: none;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1em;

  ul.primary-nav {
    margin-top: 5em;
  }
  
  li {
    color: white
  }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHQrC.jpg - screen in VSC with **problems**

Comment: How does it look when you correct the typo (missing colon after grid-template-columns) and sort out an acceptable value for -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr

Comment: Thank you! I’m pretty it's fine now. But there is one even weirder problem that didn't occur before, any ideas on that one? https://imgur.com/a/ANlezCc

Comment: What happens if you don't try to nest the settings but put a } before the ul.primary-....

Comment: both li and ul.primary-nav work when not nested, but I would like it to stay that way, because second setting that has been nested works fine (as shown os screenshot), and I want to change only li specific to .nav. I guess that using li.nav separately should work, but that nesting bothers me, as I can't explain it. https://imgur.com/a/MFk1uQ6

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you make just enough of your code into a working snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Incidentally you have the tag ssas which I assume should be sass?

Comment: Well, I suppose that @Nick was right and 'they are trying to strengthen the CSS formatting by normalizing design practices' so the nesting problem is solved just by using separate settings, and as far as the first problem goes, it has been handled by your solution that replaced specific numbers with '1fr', so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the answer you are looking for, I have identified just how to make your code runnable. I had to take yours, which is this:

```
.portfolio {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[6];
      grid-template-columns repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 300px 400px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
```

And switched to:

```
.portfolio {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    /* the line below bracket notation does not work… 
    not sure how to fix this, just removed the number. */
    -ms-grid-columns: (1fr) [];
    /* the line below was missing a ':' */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 300px 400px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
```

Please do tell me how different are the things that are displayed now on your website.

**Update! 10/2/2022 12:10**
The issue with the following code is your nesting

```
.nav {
  display: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 66%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: none;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1em;

  ul.primary-nav {
    margin-top: 5em;
  }
  
  li {
    color: white
  }

}
```

I do not believe it is customary to have tags inside other tags as you have it above. You can definitely achieve the same thing without the nesting such as with this:

```
.nav {
    display: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 66%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: none;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 1em;

}

ul .primary-nav {
    margin-top: 5em;
}

li {
    color: white
}
```

or if you have specificity problems like so:

```
.nav {
    display: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 66%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: none;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 1em;

}

ul .primary-nav .nav {
    margin-top: 5em;
}

li .nav {
    color: white
}
```

I think they are trying to strengthen the CSS formatting by normalizing design practices. Have you tried using other IDE's like Intellij's Webstorm (paid software) or Brackets 2.0 (open-source maintained now)?

Comment: after removing the numbers inside of the brackets it shows no error but without them it changes the display on my website :( yesterday it was working fine, I really have no idea what caused it or how to fix it.

Comment: @DB_vagabond I have given an answer for the second code excerpt you provided, but I am afraid that I just have never used `ms-grid-columns` to know how to handle the bracket number.

Answer (score 0):

By Using the solution's given in the comments i have solved my problem as follows:

**First problem**

```
.portfolio {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 300px 400px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
```

**The second problem**

```
.nav {
  display: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 66%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: none;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1em;
}

ul.primary-nav {
  margin-top: 5em;
}

li.nav {
  color: white
}
```

Thank's for all the help!